# Do Possessive Pronouns Always Agree with the Thing Being Possessed?

Tags: pronouns, agreement

I recently came across this sentence (a practice sentence with no given answer) in my Latin textbook:

> *mare nostrum plurimos portus habet*

I translated this as 'The sea has most of our harbour.'

However I am not sure that I have got this translation right as *nostrum* and *plurimos* are both accusative plural. Is *portus* a partitive genitive?

Should it not be:

> *mare plurimos nostrorum portus habet*

Where *nostrorum* agrees in case with *portus*?

Comment: While there are languages where possessives, other adjectives or even nouns give information about a counterpart (like the owner, for example), it is not the case of Latin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, the most likely translation of the sentece is:

> Our sea has many docks

`Mare Nostrum` was a common name given by the Romans to the Mediterranean Sea around the I century AD, since the empire possesed all of its coast by that time.

Regarding your question in the title, **yes** adjectives and pronouns must agree in gender, number *and* case with the respective noun. In this case, `nostrum` acts as an adjective, since it isn't replacing any nouns.

`Mare` and `nostrum` are *neuters* in nominative, singular (sing. neut. are the same in nom., voc., and acc.).

`Portus` belongs to the fourth declension, meaning that it forms its accusative plural with -us, just as its nom. singular. In this case, `portus` agrees with `plurimos` to say *many docks* as the object of the verb `habere` (hence it is not in genitive).

**Edit:** about the alternative sentence you offered: Since `portus` is plural, `mare plurimos nostrorum portus habet` agrees in number: no need for partitive plural. However, as @brianpck notes, portus should change to `portuum` in order to be in genitive and agree with `nostrorum`, so that the sentence can mean *The sea has most of our harbours*.

Hope it helps